# Making one executable depend on another in Haskell cabal

Tags: haskell, dependencies, cabal, haskell-platform

How do I make one executable in a cabal file depend on another in the same project?

I have a cabal file that builds two executables. One of the executables is a code generator that produces a Haskell source code file that the second executable depends on. How do I tell cabal to compile and run the first one before the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They need to be separate projects - two .cabal files.

See e.g the gtk2hs preprocessor - http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk2hs-buildtools